# Can't seem to get .getch() to work (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, pycharm, getch

I'm trying to detect a key press to determine whether the user wants to play again, but msvcrt.getch() is just not working for me. This is my code:

```
import msvcrt
#the game here
    print "Do you want to continue? Y/N"
    if msvcrt.getch() == 'Y' or msvcrt.getch() == 'y':
        print"Let's play again!"
        print"-----------------"
    elif msvcrt.getch() == 'N' or msvcrt.getch() == 'n' :
        "Okay, hope you had fun"
        break
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** The answers below do work on the command line, for some reason just don't in PyCharm

Comment: Do you have any errors when you run your code?

Comment: You need to call `getch()` __once__, then compare that value four times.  As it is, you're only comparing the user's initial keypress against `Y`, then requesting a second keypress..

Comment: @cosinepenguin @jasonharper No errors, just doesn't register any key press, as if `getch()` doesn't even get called for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call `msvcrt.getch()` once. Change your code to something like this:

```
import msvcrt
#the game here
    print "Do you want to continue? Y/N"
    response = msvcrt.getch()
    if response.lower() == 'y':
        print"Let's play again!"
        print"-----------------"
    elif response.lower == 'n' :
        "Okay, hope you had fun"
        break
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but it  it still doesn't work. Just doesn't seem to register the key press for some reason.